# Can I link multiple .lib in C++

Tags: c++

If I have a library "a.lib" that I include in project B, then I generate B.lib. 
Then in a  3rd project if I want to use functions from library a is it sufficient to include B.lib? or do I need to include a.lib also?

So basically by addind a.lib to the LIBS path of project b does it link into b.lib automatically even if I don't use any of its function in project b?

Comment: It depends on how you configure project 'a' as to whether it incorporates the contents of b. By default it will not.

Comment: Please confirm your compiler and OS version. The answers will vary.

Comment: Is something stopping you from trying it?

Answer (score -2):

No. when compiling an application you will need to add both to the linkage path. however you can join libs to a single one ("ar" in linux, don't know how its done on windows).